# Transaction management in Filenet over EJB Transport

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I am new to IBM Filenet P8. I can successfully upload and dowwnload files from filenet. But I need transaction management so for that i went to EJB Transort. But I do no how to rollback the files when exception occurs.I am using spring and hibernate and i do no how to configure JTA for filenet in spring

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, EJB transations are on so you don't need to do anything. If a document is persisted within a transaction and an exception occurs, the creation of the document is rolled back.

Comment: What you described has nothing to do with EJB transactions. It's just the atomicity of a single operation.

Comment: @fnt, what are you talking about? OP is using EJB and the transactions are on by default, and an exception during creation or modification will roll back the changes in a FileNet document.